# Remove Affiliate Query String from Url Javascript

Tags: javascript, pushstate

In my shopping cart I create affiliate urls like so:

```
http://mysite.local/phones-and-pdas/iphone?z=5509d173cffeb
```

I'd like to use history.pushState to remove the query string starting at the ?.

I've tried using `slice()` and `split()` but this seems to effect other urls as well, even when they don't contain `?z=`

```
function trackingLink() {
    var href = window.location.href;
    var url  = href.slice(0, href.indexOf('?z='));

    history.pushState(null, null, url);
}
```

For example when I go to:

```
http://mysite.local/account/dashboard
```

The address url is changed to:

```
http://mysite.local/account/dashboar
```

As a note, the above code does work perfectly on the affiliate link.

I'm sure this is a simple tweak but I couldn't find a specific answer when searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function trackingLink() {
var href = window.location.href;
var url  = href.split('?z=');
history.pushState(null, null, url[0]);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  I tried split but I did it wrong.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) instead of [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

`href.split('?')[0]` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Add a check to see if `?z=` there in the first place:

```
var href = window.location.href;
if(href.indexOf('?z=')) {
    var url  = href.slice(0, href.indexOf('?z='));
    history.pushState(null, null, url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborte on +DaveS's answer:

```
var href = window.location.href;
var url = href.split("?")[0];
history.pushState(null, document.title, url);
```